# App Store Connect Operation Error

Tags: swift, xcode, app-store

Estoy tratando de subir mi app a appStore pero sin éxito, el error es :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el error consta de actualizar al Xcode y poner el SDK de una de las versiones recientes, por lo tanto lo envió así pero sin éxito

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco cualquier información.

Comment: Que version de Xcode estás utilizando?

Comment: Gracias, si era la version de xcode se a actualizado unos dos dias antes de que quise subir y ese era el problema, me pedia que este en su ultima version. mil gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solucion fue descargar la actualizacion que a pedido, justo unos dos dias antes de subir.
mi version era 5.2
version a actualizar 5.2.1